# Postgresql 9.6 InitDB Fails

Tags: postgresql, rhel, rhel7, postgresql-9.6

Whenever I Try running the command below it always fails on RHEL7. I've tried on another similar OS (Newer) and it doesn't do this and just works.

I'v looked into permissions of directories, disabled selinux (Just incase) and also looked into locales, however these settings match that of my other server.

```
/usr/pgsql-9.6/bin/postgresql96-setup initdb
```

Log output:

```
The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_US.UTF-8".
The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8".
The default text search configuration will be set to "english".

Data page checksums are disabled.

fixing permissions on existing directory /var/lib/pgsql/9.6/data ... ok
creating subdirectories ... ok
selecting default max_connections ... 100
selecting default shared_buffers ... 64MB
selecting dynamic shared memory implementation ... posix
creating configuration files ... ok
running bootstrap script ... < 2017-10-23 20:13:54.035 BST > LOG:  invalid value for parameter "lc_messages": "en_US.UTF-8"
< 2017-10-23 20:13:54.035 BST > LOG:  invalid value for parameter "lc_monetary": "en_US.UTF-8"
< 2017-10-23 20:13:54.035 BST > LOG:  invalid value for parameter "lc_numeric": "en_US.UTF-8"
< 2017-10-23 20:13:54.035 BST > LOG:  invalid value for parameter "lc_time": "en_US.UTF-8"
< 2017-10-23 20:13:54.035 BST > FATAL:  configuration file "/var/lib/pgsql/9.6/data/postgresql.conf" contains errors
child process exited with exit code 1
initdb: removing contents of data directory "/var/lib/pgsql/9.6/data"
```

Comment: You can create a symlink (or copy) in the /usr/lib/locale' directory; or can use `initdb --locale=LOCALE` to override your locale settings. You could also use `--no-locale` or `--locale=C` to make the system assume nothing.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the system does not recognize the `en_US.UTF-8` locale as valid.

Did you apply any steps to minimize the set of installed locales?  What's the size of your `/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive` file?  It should be around 100 MiB.  You could also compare it with a fresh installation, just to be sure (`rpm -V` does not work for this file).

Comment: The directory is 102M, I have also tried with en_GB.UTF-8 using the initdb command without the setup command.

Answer (score 0):

When running through the windows 10 installer and selecting US English as my locale, I see that the parameter is `English_United States.1252`, i.e.:

```
lc_messages = 'English_United States.1252'
lc_monetary = 'English_United States.1252'
lc_numeric = 'English_United States.1252'
lc_time = 'English_United States.1252'
```

To me, my initdb also failed because I had chosen the `default` locale option, which was just an empty string. When selecting this option, however, the db got initiated. I don't know if this solves your particular issue, but maybe it helps someone else out there!

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered this issue and it seems to have been caused by a missing locale. My Postgres configuration file was using `en_GB.utf8`.

Fixed by installing the locale:

```
localedef -i en_GB -c -f UTF-8 -A /usr/share/locale/locale.alias en_GB.UTF-8
```

And setting the `LANG` environment variable to `en_GB.utf8`.

---

I've found the fix in [Postgres Docker image docs](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/) (Section "Locale Customization").